# ndimage missing from scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use the ndimage library from scipy, but its apparently missing. I have run the tests from both numpy and scipy and the results were OK. I am using numpy 1.6.1 and scipy 0.10.0 installed from the official packages on sourceforge.

Running

```
import numpy
import scipy
import pprint

print(scipy.version.version)
print(numpy.version.version)

img = scipy.ndimage.imread("")
```

gives

```
0.10.0
1.6.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract.py", line 8, in <module>
    img = scipy.ndimage.imread("")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ndimage'
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have to import the module:

```
import scipy.ndimage
```

Comment: I have the same problem and got fixed now using your method. But in my ipython interpreter, after `import scipy`, using `scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter1d` does not throw errors. Why is that?

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html#guidelines-for-importing-functions-from-scipy for details

Answer (score 18):

Modules should be imported like this:

```
from  scipy import ndimage
```

Comment: Are you sure about this syntax?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html

imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use `imageio.imread` instead.

Answer (score -2):

Locate the *init* file in scipy and add import ndimage